# How to send files to HDFS using Solr

Tags: hadoop, indexing, solr, hdfs

I am trying to index files and keep these files on HDFS.

I am using Solr 4.10.4 and Hadoop 2.6.0.

The command I use for integration HDFS and Solr is;

```
java -Dsolr.directoryFactory=HdfsDirectoryFactory -Dsolr.lock.type=hdfs -Dsolr.data.dir=hdfs://<hostname>:<port>/Solr -Dsolr.updatelog=hdfs://<hostname>:<port>/Solr-logs -jar start.jar
```

When I try to send some files using

```
java -jar post.jar <file-path>
```

command, Solr gives warning and does not send it to hdfs. It only accepts **xml** format with specific fields.

How can I send any kind of file using Solr for indexing to HDFS and do search on these files using Solr.

Note: I am beginner on Solr and Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

if want to index other file format you can specify document type as like below

```
java -Dtype=text/csv -jar post.jar *.csv
```

By default below command takes care of all possible file types that Apache Tika can handle

```
java -Dauto -jar post.jar *.*
```